# Determinant of a positive definite (non-symmetric) bilinear form on ${\Bbb R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a *symmetric* matrix $M$ over ${\Bbb R}$, we have the result that if $M$ is positive definite, then $\det M>0$. I'm wondering if this is also true in general:

> if $M$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix with $\langle x,Mx\rangle>0$ for all $x\not=0$ where $\langle ,\rangle$ is the standard inner product in $\Bbb{R}^n$, do we have $\det M>0$?

---

By considering the eigenvalues of $M$, one can say that this must be true when $M$ is diagonalizable. What if $M$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: I'd put it in Jordan normal form and show that the diagonal entries are positive by taking xi to infinity with the other components zero.

Comment: Or rather, evaluate for the basis vectors.

Comment: @GitGud, all right. I've removed my comments too, since they wouldn't make much sense with your comment removed. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $\langle x, Mx\rangle>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$ with $x\neq 0$. $M$ cannot have a negative eigenvalue $\lambda$, because then there would be a corresponding eigenvector $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and we would have $$\langle x, Mx\rangle = \langle x, \lambda x\rangle = \lambda \langle x,x\rangle < 0$$ So all eigenvalues of $M$ are either positive or complex. The complex eigenvalues come in complex-conjugate pairs $\{z, \overline z\}$, and the product $z\overline z=|z|^2$ of such a pair is positive. Therefore, the product of all the eigenvalues of $M$ is positive, which means $\text{det}(M)$ is positive.